# JsonNode returning null when findValue method is invoked?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Here is an example json

```
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": {
            "key3": "value3"
        }
    }
 }
```

I want to get the value of key3, which is "value3"
The method `findValue` of `JsonNode` class should serve the purpose here.

so I tried the following:

```
final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

String jsonRoot = "{\"key1\":\n" + "    {\"key2\":\n" + "            {\"key3\":\"value3\"}\n" + "    }\n" + "}";
JsonNode node = jsonMapper.convertValue(jsonRoot,JsonNode.class);
JsonNode found = node.findValue("key3");
System.out.println(found.asText());
System.out.println(found.isObject());
```

However, I see "found" is null.
I am unable to figure out why this failing. I also tried node.findValue("key2"). I still get null.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convertValue function is used to convert one instance type into another instance type. It is a two step conversion process which is equivalent to first serializing given value into JSON, then binding JSON data into value of second given type.

In your example above, the first argument of convertValue is actually a JSON(represented in a string) and not an object, hence this does not work.

To make this work, you can use following methods :

## Method 1 :

JsonNode node = jsonMapper.readTree(jsonRoot);

This will deserialize the json as a tree and  returns the root of the tree which can be used for traversal now.

## Method 2 :

JsonNode node = jsonMapper.readValue(jsonRoot, JsonNode.class);

This will deserialize the json to JsonNode object directly.

Answer (score 5):

There is difference in between these 2 methods

1. JsonNode.get() method returns null
2. Use JsonNode.path(String).asText() which checks if node is present or
   not, if not then it returns empty string.

Answer (score 2):

So something like this should work.(although untested)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(new File("c:\\example.json"));
JsonNode key1Node = root.path("key1");
JsonNode key2Node = key1Node.path("key2");
```

access value of key 3 node

```
String val = key2Node.path("key3").asText();
```

See Reference [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-tree-model-example/).

Comment: I would like to know why the above did not work..I am aware of alternative solutions..